# Manipulation DOM in saga redux

Tags: redux-saga

I have application with long list and click last element must scroll to top page. What best decision: use react-scroll or use saga for this task?

And use saga for manipulate DOM and web page the good way?

Answer (score 0):

> What best decision: use react-scroll or use saga for this task?

`Saga` is commonly applicable for long-running process, affecting `redux` state in asynchronous manner, like API call or optimistic update. Often redux state includes information about domain and presentation layers, so, if actual UI state is stored in `redux` store, there is no barrier to use `saga` to manipulate it.

For example, there is library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-redux-scroll to support scrolling using `saga` and listening actions respectively. In other words, manipulation of state in one point, at root of redux state, by `saga` processes - is best use case.